# Listview Get li ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a list view dynamically and assigned each `li` item its own unique ID. I am using jQuery mobile and what I am trying to do is when I user clicks on a list item, I need it to start JS function to pull the information from the web api and then load a new screen.

```
<ul id="stationlist" data-role="listview">
    <li onclick="getInfo()" id="12345">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo()" id="23561">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo()" id="55844">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo()" id="12458">Some text</li>

</ul>
```

How can I accomplish this when the user click on the listview item it calls the function and get the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass you dom element by this way and get id information.

```
<ul id="stationlist" data-role="listview">
    <li onclick="getInfo(this)" id="12345">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo(this)" id="23561">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo(this)" id="55844">Some text</li>
    <li onclick="getInfo(this)" id="12458">Some text</li>
</ul>

<script>
function getInfo(target){
  var idOfTag=target.id;
}
</script>
```